# Is it possible to mandate 2FA configuration during user registration?

Tags: fusionauth

I have set up the fustionAuth server and am able to register users - I am also able to configure token based 2FA for a user via the API.

Is there any way to require 'require' a user to configure 2FA before they can log in? I'm aware that I could add it procedurally to each app as I develop it, but I would also like to enforce it at a rule at the identity server side.

Additionally.. are there any plans to support U2F keys as an additional form of 2FA?

Answer (score 1):

We are planning on adding the ability for users to setup 2FA during registration and the ability to require it to be enabled as well. We also have plans to add the ability to enable 2FA during login.

Similarly, we also are looking at adding U2F support for 2FA in the future.

I'm not positive what release these features will be in because they are currently in the backlog and not scheduled. If you would like to open a GitHub issue and vote on it, if it gets enough votes we will put it to the top of the queue.